# How to convert a binary string to its 2's complement in MIPS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a MIPS Assembly program that takes in a  negative integer from user input, finds the absolute value of that number, then converts it to a binary string. I want to be able to find the 2's complement of the number by flipping the binary string that is calculated (changing all 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's), then add a 1 to the Least Significant Bit (while carrying a 1 to the higher bits if necessary). I am not really sure how to go about implementing this; any help would be greatly appreciated. I have posted my current program below for reference

```
.data
  #declare strings
  readMsg: asciiz "Enter a negative number:"
  printBinary: .asciiz "Binary Number :"
  space: .asciiz " "
  outOfRange: .asciiz "number is not negative!"

 .text
 .globl main
 main:
    #prompt the user to enter a negative number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, readMsg
    syscall
    #read integer from the user
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    #if user input is positive, exit. if negative, find absolute value and continue
    bgt $v0, $zero, exit
    sub $v0, $zero, $v0
    blt $v0, $zero, continue

    continue:
      #move to input value to register $s0
      move $s0, $v0
      #print the string binary number
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, printBinary
      syscall

    #jump and link to the calculateBinary
    jal calculateBinary
    #end the program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

    #calculate the binary string of integer
    calculateBinary:
      #move input $s0 into $t0
      add $t0, $zero, $s0
      #move 0 into $t1
      add $t1, $zero, $zero
      #load 1 as a mask
      addi $t3, $zero, 1
      #shift  left the value of $t3 by 7 positions
      sll $t3, $t3, 7
      addi $t4, $zero, 8 #loop counter

      #perform AND with input and mask
    loop:
      and $t1, $t0, $t3
      #branch to print if 0
      beq $t1, $zero, printBinValue
      #move 0 into $t1
      add $t1, $zero, $zero
      #put a 1 in $t1
      addi $t1, $zero, 1
      j printBinValue

    printBinValue:
       #print value
       li $v0, 1
       move $a0, $t1
       syscall
       #putspace
       beq $t4, 5, printSpace
       j loop2

    printSpace:
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, space
      syscall

    loop2:
      #shift right by 1 position
      srl $t3, $t3, 1
      addi $t4, $t4, -1
      bne $t4, $zero, loop
      #return to main
      jr $ra

     exit:
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, outOfRange
       syscall
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question.  You just start with an integer, not a string of base 2 digits of ASCII `'0'` and `'1'` characters.  You aren't trying to manipulate something like that without converting to a binary integer in a register and back.  If you know the input is negative, subtract it from 0 like `sub $t1, $zero, $a0` to make it positive.

Comment: If you can program arrays, loops and indices in any other language, implement your program in that. Then convert it into the equivalent in assembly. It should be straightforward.